# How to share an Arraylist through Intent.ACTION_SEND

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

i'm developing an App which has an Arraylist with the name of the product and its quantity. Now i want to make an Intent to share this information like a list through the WhatsApp, email or whatever he is able.
Example:

```
List<Compartilhar> listaCompras2 = new ArrayList<>( );

//listaCompras2 has a for loop to to get a new content every time the client input a product and quantity.
listaCompras2.add(new Compartilhar(doc.getString("inputNome"), doc.getString("inputQtd")));

fabShare = view.findViewById(R.id.fabShare);
fabShare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener( ) {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    for (int i=0 ; i < listaCompras2.size(); i++)
    {
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Produto: " + listaCompras2.get(0).getProduto() + "      Qtd: " + listaCompras2.get(0).);
        i++;
    }
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "share Via"));
}
});
```

import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.List;

public class Compartilhar implements Parcelable {

```
private List<String> produto;
private List<String> qtd;

public Compartilhar(List<String> produto, List<String> qtd) {
    this.produto = produto;
    this.qtd = qtd;
}

public List<String> getProduto() {
    return produto;
}

public void setProduto(List<String> produto) {
    this.produto = produto;
}

public List<String> getQtd() {
    return qtd;
}

public void setQtd(List<String> qtd) {
    this.qtd = qtd;
}

protected Compartilhar(Parcel in) {
    if (in.readByte() == 0x01) {
        produto = new ArrayList<String>();
        in.readList(produto, String.class.getClassLoader());
    } else {
        produto = null;
    }
    if (in.readByte() == 0x01) {
        qtd = new ArrayList<String>();
        in.readList(qtd, String.class.getClassLoader());
    } else {
        qtd = null;
    }
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    if (produto == null) {
        dest.writeByte((byte) (0x00));
    } else {
        dest.writeByte((byte) (0x01));
        dest.writeList(produto);
    }
    if (qtd == null) {
        dest.writeByte((byte) (0x00));
    } else {
        dest.writeByte((byte) (0x01));
        dest.writeList(qtd);
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public static final Parcelable.Creator<Compartilhar> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Compartilhar>() {
    @Override
    public Compartilhar createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Compartilhar(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Compartilhar[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Compartilhar[size];
    }
};
```

}

Answer (score 0):

To put an ArrayList into the intent you can use the 
**putParcelableArrayListExtra(String name, ArrayList value)** method. Please pay attention that this method allows to pass a list of items what implements the **Parcelable** interface. So in your case, your **Compartilhar** class should implement the **Parcelable** interface.

As i understand you want share these items to other apps, it can be tricky, because every standalone app(Whatsapp, etc.) has it's own logic how they handles/parses the data from the intent.

Comment: So is there any way i can turn this Arraylist into a doc and then share this doc?

Comment: You can probably create a local file and write your list into this file (and format the file), then send an implicit share intent with this file, and see what app can handle your intent.

Comment: As your first answer said, i implemented my class Compartilhar and edited this post. How can i change my code now to make it send the list?